# Add File System directory as resource directory in SpringBoot Application

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to add some resources on the fly(means at the time of runtime of Jar application ) but the challenging part is : I cannot change the Jar content at runtime, so I need to create some other space as resource directory and try to fetch from there. (Is this Best Practice ? if not then please provide the solution)

**Example :** 
my spring boot application's Jar resides in File System here :

```
/home/my_spring_project/target/myproject.jar
```

**To run** : `java -jar /home/my_spring_project/target/myproject.jar`

and I have kept runtime upload Image resources in

```
/home/my_spring_project/uploads/user1_image.jpg
```

But I am not able to make the `/home/my_spring_project/uploads` directory as resource directory

**Here is my code of spring application, where I am trying to specify the resource directory separately :**

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

private static final String[] RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

private static final String UPLOAD_DIR = "/uploads"; //currently application is mapping to base_dir of project i.e. /home/my_spring_project

@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
{
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**"))
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
    registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**").addResourceLocations(UPLOAD_DIR);
}
```

}

I also need the bydefault resource directory which choosen by spring application as I will keep the frontend modules there.

I just want add one more directory apart from JAR, where I can upload any file at runtime. So that I don't need to change in content in the JAR packaging.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you try mapping the upload location like this: "file:///home/my_spring_project/uploads/"? Can you make sure that the unix user running your application has the right to read that folder?

Comment: Yeah It worked, when I provided the absolute path of the directory

Comment: But what if I want to provide the relative path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I provide absolute path, So the solution is, we can pass runtime parameter to our application :

```
@Configuration
public class StaticResourceConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{

@Value("${upload.location}")
private String uploadLocation;

private static final String[] RESOURCE_LOCATIONS = { "classpath:/META-INF/resources/", "classpath:/resources/", "classpath:/static/", "classpath:/public/" };

  @Override
  public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry)
  {
    if (!registry.hasMappingForPattern("/**"))
    {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocations(RESOURCE_LOCATIONS);
    }
    registry.addResourceHandler("/uploads/**").addResourceLocations(uploadLocation);
  }
}
```

So while running the application , we need to provide the parameter value like this :

```
java -jar /home/my_spring_project/target/myproject.jar --upload.location=file:/home/my_spring_project/uploads
```

Thanks to @Brian Clozel